# getInitialState is giving me an error "Objects are not valid as a React child"

Tags: javascript, react-native

Just started learning React native and have been using Udemy to get the hang of things and this error has me stumped. I followed the tutorial to the letter.

```
getInitialState:function(){
  return {
    timeElapsed:null
  }
},

render:function(){
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style ={[styles.header,this.border('yellow')]}>
        <View style={[styles.timerWrapper,this.border('red')]}>
          <Text>
            {this.state.timeElapsed}
          </Text>
        </View>
        <View style={[styles.buttonWrapper,this.border('green')]}> 
          {this.startStopButton()}
          {this.lapButton()}
        </View>
      </View>
      <View style={[styles.footer, this.border('blue')]}>
        <Text>
          I am a list of laps 
        </Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
},

startStopButton: function(){
  return (
    <TouchableHighlight underlayColor="green"
      onPress={this.handleStartPress}>
      <Text>
        Starts
      </Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  );
}
```

The error message states that I am trying to return more than 1 object from getInitialState function. From the examples I could find online, this seems to be the correct format. What am I missing here.

The entire error message is: Objects are not valid as a React child. If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment.

Comment: Can you add the code for the `lapButton` method?

Answer (score 0):

I think the code below caused the error, `this.state.timeElapsed` must be a React-Node. You may return a javascript object in `timeElapsed`, something like Date instance.

```
<Text>
  {this.state.timeElapsed}
</Text>
```

If you don't sure what is React-Node, you can read the official docs about that [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/glossary.html#nodes-and-elements).